# typeScript указание типа в декораторе

Tags: typescript

Есть вот такой код.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
import 'joi-extract-type'

const MathSumParamsV1 = Joi.object({
  a: Joi.number().required(),
  b: Joi.number().required(),
  str: Joi.string().required()
})

@controller('math.sum')
class MathSumController {
  @implementation('0.0.1')
  @params(MathSumParamsV1)
  public v1 = (params: Joi.extractType<typeof MathSumParamsV1>): number => {
```

Как видно передаю два раза MathSumParamsV1 в декоратор и в параметры функции.
Хотелось бы избавится от `Joi.extractType<typeof MathSumParamsV1>`

Comment: код лучше выкладывать текстом, а не картинкой)

Comment: @ThisMan Пожалуйста

Comment: а как ты предполагаешь это должно выглядеть?

Comment: Декаратор должен указывать тип

Comment: я имел ввиду, как это должно выглядеть в коде?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-yn5szj

Comment: @Grundy, вероятно, `@implementation('0.0.1')
  @params(MathSumParamsV1)
  public v1 = params => {`. Но вроде ts так не умеет...